# How can I generate an answer without a user input in Watson Conversation Service?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

At some point in the dialogue it may happen that there are no questions asked by the user, and it is necessary for the system to react to the user through a message. How to do this?

Comment: Please don't SHOUT; people do not like being shouted at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversation is stateless. So you need to handle this at the application layer. You would have the application layer after a set time send a message to conversation to get it to respond.

Answer (score 0):

It's a conversation service, so the idea is to respond to user input. As **Simon** has mentioned, it needs to be handled by the application. Let's say the user doesn't type anything for a certain time, so application should be making a call to Conversation Service after that time interval with a specific text for No response intent that can trigger the node that you have designed for **#No_Response**. The response from this node can then be shown back to the user.